# Amazon S3 Get Bucket List - Rest API

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using Amazon S3 REST API for listing the contents of my bucket. I am able to establish a connection and get the list of my buckets with request URL being "https://s3.amazonaws.com" and `http_request_type = "GET"`. However when I try to list the contents of the bucket I am getting an error

> AuthorizationHeaderMalformed The authorization header is malformed; incorrect service "balas3bucke01". This endpoint belongs to "s3".

**balas3bucke01 is the name of the bucket.**

My request URL is https://balas3bucke01.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
http_request_type = "GET"

Why am I getting the above error.

Comment: What are you passing in for an Authorization header?

Comment: Thanks @Jason. Header is

1. Connection Request
Host: s3.amazonaws.com
Date:
x-amz-content-sha256:e3b**855
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=XXX/20150618/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=date;host;x-amz-content-sha256, Signature=ec**7518
Canonical Request:
GET

2. For Getting the Contents
Host: balas3bucke01.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
Date:
x-amz-content-sha256:e3b*855
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=XXX/20150618/ap-southeast-1/balas3bucke01/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=date;host;x-amz-content-sha256, Signature=fd**1429

Please let me know where am i going wrong

Comment: @BalajiKrishnan Were you able to solve this issue? I'm having a similar problem: my requests succeed with path-style urls but fail when virtual-hosted-styled.